# Phyloseq and Heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, phyloseq

I am analyzing 16s microbiome data from the lung and mouth and I'm basically teaching myself R. So I made it through qiime and have uploaded two files into R. My OTU table using:

```
otu=import_biom('C:\Users\OneDrive\otu_table.biom')
```

and my sort of "map" file which just contains SampleID, Location, and Paired. For example:

```
 SampleID  Location   Paired
 1_L       Lung       1
 1_M       Mouth      1
 2_L       Lung       2
 2_M       Mouth      2
```

code:

```
map=read.csv('C:\Users\OneDrive\Mouth vs lung R map_adj.csv',
             header=T,row.name=1,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

My data is paired and I want to compare the lung vs the mouth using a heatmap. I've been having trouble with R. First off it won't let me do it by location. I've tried:

```
plot_heatmap(otu, sample.label="SampleType")
```

And I got this error:

```
Error in get_variable(physeq, sample.label) :
Your phyloseq data object does not have a sample-data component
Try ?sample_data for more details.
```

I went to `?sample_data` and I have no idea what I am missing here.

Secondly, I'd like to do it by location and paired if that makes sense.

Can anyone help me with this code and maybe explain what it is I'm missing here, because I also have data where I look at the lung microbiome at baseline and then again 2 months later so that also is paired data.

Thank you for your help!

Here is my whole code:

```
library("phyloseq")
packageVersion("phyloseq")

otu=import_biom('C:\Users\closed-ref-33031010\otu_table.biom')

map=read.csv('C:\Users\Qiime Maps\Mouth vs lung R map_adj.csv',
             header=T,row.name=1,stringsAsFactors=F)

sampledata1=sample_data(map)

otu2=merge_phyloseq(otu,sampledata1)
plot_heatmap(otu2)
```

In addition, I'm unsure how to make a phyloseq object

Comment: Looks like you have multiple questions. Questions that are more specific will usually attract better answers. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is carefully described on a help page dedicated to the topic:

https://joey711.github.io/phyloseq/import-data.html

Unless your question is about something specifically lacking/confusing on that help page, I think this link answers the question.

As a commentor mentioned, if you do get that specific, someone is more likely to provide a precise and useful answer.